# vectorize Pandas tqdm progress_apply function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science, tqdm

I created a function to drop geocoordinates outside a shapefile.
The code below works.

```
...
import shapefile
from shapely.geometry import Point 
from shapely.geometry import shape 
from tqdm import tqdm
tqdm.pandas()

df = pd.read_stata(r'C:PathtoDataFrame')
shp = shapefile.Reader(r'C:PathtoShapeFile') 
all_shapes = shp.shapes() 
all_records = shp.records() 

def InCountry(lo,la):
    point_to_check = (lo, la) # longitude & latitude
    for i in range(len(all_shapes)):
        boundary = all_shapes[i] # get a boundary polygon
        if Point(point_to_check).within(shape(boundary)): 
            return (1)
        else:
            pass    

df_copy = df.progress_apply(lambda x: InCountry(x.geopointlongitude, x.geopointlatitude), axis=1)
```

The problem is that it takes forever to run on a large dataframe.
How can I speed up and optimize the apply function?

EDIT:
Here are details of shape file

```
Number of Shapes: 37
Number of points: 1194
```

Printout of the polygons

````
....
 (9.384363174438477, 8.204757690429688),
 (9.382139205932617, 8.20582389831543),
 (9.38012409210205, 8.208586692810059),
 (9.374833106994629, 8.211809158325195),
 (9.371249198913574, 8.215107917785645),
 (9.364250183105469, 8.218253135681152),
 (9.35895824432373, 8.221475601196289),
 (9.35374927520752, 8.222970962524414),
 (9.346748352050781, 8.226116180419922),
 (9.34145736694336, 8.229338645935059),
 (9.336165428161621, 8.232561111450195),
 (9.329566955566406, 8.236310005187988),
 (9.325902938842773, 8.245444297790527),
 (9.323423385620117, 8.253451347351074),
 (9.325519561767578, 8.263849258422852),
....

```
````

Comment: You need to vectorize. You properly need to look at the Point.within function and see if you can vectorize it. Is the bondary polygons convex?

Comment: Can you give some statistics number of shapes, total number of edges in the polygons and number of points

Comment: And can you print the polygons and the points?

Comment: Maybe this question could be interesting https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/167118/find-country-from-gps-coordinates-offline-using-python

Comment: I've edited the question with the Statistics of the shapefile, how can I vectorize?

Comment: It is not a simple answer. But if your data is geo data and your shapes are countries. Then there are existing libaries doing this for you very fast. Maybe https://github.com/thampiman/reverse-geocoder could be a candidate.

Comment: Thanks, I have experience with reverse-geocoder, unfortunately, most libraries require access to an external API with their own limitations